# Python; sys.setrecursionlimit within function

Tags: python, recursion

The following code is a simplified example where I want to set recursionlimit inside a wrapper function:

```
import sys

def _f(m): #not meant to be useful, just an example
  if m == 0:
    return 1
  else:
    return 4*_f(m-1)

def f(m):
  sys.setrecursionlimit(m+2)
  _f(m)

f(5000)

...
File "<stdin>", line 5, in _f
File "<stdin>", line 5, in _f
File "<stdin>", line 5, in _f
File "<stdin>", line 5, in _f
File "<stdin>", line 5, in _f
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Why does this happen?

Comment: Can't you just rewrite the function to use an accumulator?

Comment: Calling `f()` will count as one level of recursion each time it's called, are you accounting for that with the value you're passing?

Comment: @kay this code is simplified greatly. I trimmed it down to the simplest thing I could. The recursive function takes a lot more parameters.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `_f` calls `f`, which in turn calls `sys.setrecursionlimit` with a smaller recursion limit. Also, having `_f` and `f` call each other will use twice the number of stack frames.

I think you meant for `_f` to call itself.

```
def _f(m):
  if m == 0:
    return 1
  else:
    #something = ...
    return something*_f(m-1) # should call _f rather than f

def f(m):
  sys.setrecursionlimit(m+5)
  _f(m)
```

Comment: unfortunately my code here was a typo because I translated my original function names into f. It does not work with the proper fixed code either.

Comment: I rewrote my question to be a copy-pastable example.